# How to find if a string characters is present in the another string?

Tags: python

For example:

```
str1="key" chracters-['k','e','y'] 
str2="hey! let's place a knot"
```

Result:  `True`  -- [Since the characters `'k','e','y'`is present in **str2** string.]

example 2:

```
str1="pond" characters - ['p','o','n','d'] 
str2="i need some sleep"
```

Result: `True` [since `'p','o','n','d'` is present in **str2**.]

```
def findStr(str1,str2):
  count=0
  charArr1 = list(str1.lower())
  charArr2=list(str2.lower())
  for i in range(len(str1)):
    for j in range(len(str2)):
      if charArr1[i] == charArr2[j]:
        count+=1
        break
  if count==(len(charArr1)):
    return True

str1 = input()
str2 = input()
print(findStr(str1,str2))
```

The problem in this solution is that if i have more than one characters same in str1 then it will give the wrong answer.
For example :

```
str1="press" str2="Please repeat!"
```

So, in this case it should be `false` but my solution will give `true` because **str1** has two `"s"` and **str2** has only one `"s"`.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Please do not tag multiple languages in your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question/) unless your question is specifically about these languages.  You may think it will lead to a faster answer, but the reality is that it is more likely to lead to a faster closure.

Comment: Please show the solution you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution it works in your second condition also :

```
str1="press"
str2="Please repeat!" 
if all(i in str2 for i in str1):
   if all(str1.count(i) == str2.count(i) for i in str1):
        print(True)
   else:
        print(False)
else:
    print(False)
```

It will o/p : `False` Because `s` is 2 times in **str1** and only 1 time in **str2**.

**EDIT :**

Try by changing `==`  to `<=`:

```
 if all(str1.count(i) <= str2.count(i) for i in str1):
```

Comment: @user2015 Sorry I just didn't think about it. I have edited the answer..try the edited one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I found another solution of this using dictionary. i think your's solution is O(n^2) whereas if we use a dictionary then we will be able to solve this in linear time. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Can you please add your solution ?

Comment: I have updated the solution. Please check and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
count={}
str1="press"
str2 = "Please repeat!"
for i in str1:
    if i in count:
        count[i]+=1
    else:
        count[i]=1

for j in str2:
    if j in count and count[j] !=0:
        count[j]-=1

for k in count:
    if count[k] != 0:
        print(False)
print(True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I think this solution is done in linear time whereas the other solution is quadratic. Correct me if i am wrong